# Adding MDC SASS files to angular 4 project

Tags: angular, sass, material-components

How can I import the MDC component sass files into my angular 4 project? The compiler fails to compile the .scss files because their `@import` statements aren't relative - they just point to `@material`. For example, here is the mdc-button.scss `@import` statements:

```
@import "@material/animation/variables";
@import "@material/animation/functions";
@import "@material/elevation/mixins";
@import "@material/ripple/mixins";
@import "@material/theme/mixins";
@import "@material/typography/mixins";
```

This makes the compiler fail because it cannot find `@material` because the file is in `node_modules/@material/button/mdc-button.scss` so it needs to actually `@import "../animation/variables"` etc..

The library is at https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your sass tool, (I am using Koala) you have to add the additional path information into your sass config:

```
// Sass project settings, you can edit it and set custom settings.
// An array of filesystem paths or importers which should be searched for     
//Sass templates imported with the @import directive. (I am on windows it might be 
//different for other O/S)

"includePaths": ["C:\\Users\\loggedInUser\\node_modules"],
    "requireLibs": []
```

Comment: Angular CLI handles the compiling, but this still works